# How can I use puffing-billy and VCR to prevent testing stripe's checkout from creating endless new files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, stripe-payments

I am using puffing-billy/vcr/capybara/rspec to write a feature spec that is testing my use of the stripe gem. My specs are passing but I have been unable to get puffing-billy to use cached data rather than creating new files each time I run rspec.

Is it possible to test the stripe checkout functionality without hitting the network or mocking anything else?

Comment: What record mode is VCR running in? If it's in `new_episodes` but still generating new files each time, try setting it to `none` to make debugging easier.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `merge_cached_responses_whitelist` option to merge responses. It was difficult to figure out the correct syntax for URLs, but this is what I figured out:

- The rules **MUST** be regexes. I tried using strings and it froze my tests.
- You must **NOT** include the protocol in your regex (e.g. `https?:\/\/`)
- For HTTPS urls, you must handle port `:443` after the domain

Here's my rules to cache some Stripe responses on the front-end:

```
config.merge_cached_responses_whitelist = [
  /api\.stripe\.com(:443)*\/v1\/tokens/,
  /m\.stripe\.com(:443)*\/4/
]
```

Another important tip is that `puffing-billy` logs are not printed to your console, but go directly into your test logs at `log/test.log`. It really helps if you keep an eye on your test logs with:

```
tail -f log/test.log
```

You will see lines like this:

```
puffing-billy: CACHE KEY for 'https://api.stripe.com:443/v1/tokens' is 'post_e23c813681b1bac66ef1cc6f5f1b56108a18ec52'
puffing-billy: CACHE post for 'https://api.stripe.com:443/v1/tokens'
puffing-billy: CACHE KEY for 'https://m.stripe.com:443/4' is post_8072c2c958962829d4ba630f02301dc3a51f6a6e'
puffing-billy: CACHE post for 'https://m.stripe.com:443/4'
```

Answer (score -3):

Stripe's [Checkout form](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) will always reach out to Stripe's servers. While you can use your test API key and create card tokens using the special [testing numbers](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards), there is no way to prevent Checkout from contacting Stripe's servers.

Comment: Puffing billy should be able to do this.